# Get the difference between two list?

Tags: python

I have to lists of numbers, I want to save the difference between each parallel cells
I need something like this:

```
diffEx = [(myEx - opEx) for myEx,opEx in (myExeptPack,opExeptPack)]
```

eg.

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = [4,3,2]
diff = [-3,-1,1]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
diffEx = [(myEx - opEx) for myEx,opEx in zip(myExeptPack,opExeptPack)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to make the statement more concise than when using [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
import operator
diffEx = map(operator.sub, myExeptPack, opExeptPack)
```

Comment: If you're using `map` you don't need the `zip`, eg: `map(operator.sub, myExpectPack, opExceptPack)` is fine for example given.